# Prove that $S^3\setminus S^1$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

As the titles says, I have to prove that $S^3\setminus S^1$ is connected.

I'm having a hard time solving this problem. The best idea I've come up with is to show somehow that, if $S^3\setminus S^1$ wasn't connected, then $S^1$ would be a non-trivial clopen in $S^3$, and that's a contradiction; to do this I've tried to use the fact that in these hypotheses $S^3\setminus S^1=A\cup B$ disjoint open sets and $S^3\setminus S^1=C \cup D$ disjoint closed sets, but I haven't been able to conclude anything (and I'm not sure this is the right way to proceed). Maybe I'm missing something trivial.

Any hints?

Comment: And *how* do you see $S^1$ as a subset of $S^3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the stereographic projection, you can identify $S^3-\{point\}$ (the point not in $S^1$) to $\mathbb{R}^3$. The image of the circle by the stereographic projection is a circle if the center of the stereographic projection is not in the circle. If you remove a circle to $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is still connected.

This implies that $S^3-\{point\}\cup S^1$ is connected and $S^3-S^1$ is connected.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just to make sure, the last implication "formally" follows from the fact that $S^3$ is a normal space, and I can find a connected subset of $S^3$ disjoint from $S^1$ (like a spherical cap) that I can add to $S^3$ to obtain the connected $S^3\setminus S^1$, is that right?

Comment: Something like that you can also consider that a small neighborhood of a point is a path connected since it is a ball and $S^3-S^1-\cup\{point\}$ is path connected this follow from the fact that $R^3-S^1$ is path connected.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider $\Bbb R^2 \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^4$ by $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, 0, 0)$.
Under the above, we also get $S^1 \hookrightarrow S^3$.

Consider the map $p : \Bbb R^4\setminus\{\mathbf 0\} \to S^3$ given by $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$.
Under this map, we have $p(\Bbb R^4 \setminus \Bbb R^2) = S^3 \setminus S^1$.

However, $\Bbb R^4 \setminus \Bbb R^2$ is path-connected. (Consider the broken line path.)
Thus, $S^3 \setminus S^1$ is also path-connected, being the continuous image of a path-connected space. In particular, it is connected.